# Check radio button to unset required field

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have created a select field with 4 radio buttons and 2 drop-down lists that are hidden and only become visible when the first or second radio button is checked.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="billing_piegadatajs_field">
<label for="billing_piegadatajs" class="">Piegādes veids <abbr class="required" title="vajadzīgs">*</abbr>

</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="billing_piegadatajs" value="Pasta Stacija" class="radio" style="width:10%" checked="checked"><span for="billing_piegadatajs">Pasta Stacija</span>

<br>
<input type="radio" name="billing_piegadatajs" value="Post24" class="radio" style="width:10%"><span for="billing_piegadatajs">Post 24</span>

<br>
<input type="radio" name="billing_piegadatajs" value="Kurjerdienests" class="radio" style="width:10%"><span for="billing_piegadatajs">Kurjerdienests</span>

<br>
<input type="radio" name="billing_piegadatajs" value="Saņemt uz vietas" class="radio" style="width:10%"><span for="billing_piegadatajs">Saņemt uz vietas ( Saldū )</span>

<br>
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required hidepost" id="billing_pastastacija_field">
<label for="billing_pastastacija" class="">Pasta Stacijas adrese <abbr class="required" title="vajadzīgs">*</abbr>

</label>
<select name="billing_pastastacija" id="billing_pastastacija" class="select" allow_null="1" presentation="select" display="">
    <option value="0">- Make a choice -</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required hidepost" id="billing_pakomati_field">
<label for="billing_pakomati" class="">Post 24 pakomātu adrese <abbr class="required" title="vajadzīgs">*</abbr>

</label>
<select name="billing_pakomati" id="billing_pakomati" class="select" allow_null="1" presentation="select" display="">
    <option value="0">- Make a choice -</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
</p>
```

I added this CSS

```
.hidepost {
display: none;
}
```

And this jquery that shows / hides the drop-down lists depending what radio is selected.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "Pasta Stacija") {
        $(".hidepost").hide();
        $("#billing_pastastacija_field").show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "Post24") {
        $(".hidepost").hide();
        $("#billing_pakomati_field").show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "Kurjerdienests") {
        $(".hidepost").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "Saņemt uz vietas") {
        $(".hidepost").hide();
        $(".blue").show();
    }
});
});
```

You can also view this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8BrR/10/)

What i would like to accomplish is:

- When radio button 1 with the value="Pasta Stacija" is checked, then the
  field with id="billing_pakomati_field" is UNSET to be a Required
  Field.
- When radio button 2 with the value="Post24" is checked, then the
  field with id="billing_pastastacija_field" is UNSET to be a Required
  Field.
- When radio button 3 AND 4 with the value="Kurjerdienests" and value="Saņemt uz vietas" is checked, then BOTH fields are UNSET to be Required

**This is in Wordpress / wooCommerce.**

Is this even possible with jquery ? To unset a required field in wooCommerce? The only way i know to unset a field is to use a custom function with example:

```
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
```

P.s. The fields are created using a plugin that creates custom fields, don't know if that is important.